# parseFloat & toFixed only returning 1 decimal point

Tags: javascript, arrays, floating-point, parsefloat, tofixed

Working on the below, when logging the array 'tips' it seems that the numbers pushed into it have only one decimal point.

Before adding in parseFloat it would return 2 decimal points, however it was returned as a string. Once parseFloat was added it now only seems to return a single decimal point.

Thank you.

```js
var tips = [];
var calculateTip = function(bill) {
  switch (true) {
    case bill < 50:
      tips.push(parseFloat((bill * 0.2).toFixed(2)));
      break;
    case bill >= 50 && bill < 201:
      tips.push(parseFloat((bill * 0.15).toFixed(2)));
      break;
    default:
      tips.push(parseFloat((bill * 0.10).toFixed(2)));
  }
}
calculateTip(124);
calculateTip(48);
calculateTip(268);
console.log(tips);
```

Comment: as a float, 1.20 doesn't make sense, but as a string you can have 1.20. So You have to go with string if you want two decimal points.

Comment: **Important: if you're dealing with money, you should not be using major units (eg, dollars)**. Computers (base 2) can't represent base 10 very well. Instead do what finance apps do - deal in *minor units* (cents) and then display them as dollars and cents (or whatever else) when it's time to show them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers in Javascript are output to console with as many decimal places as needed.

```js
console.log(1.0000001)
console.log(1.1)
```

All your numbers only display with one decimal point as they only have one decimal place. You should return a string instead if you want to show them with a specific precision.

```js
var tips = [];
var calculateTip = function(bill) {
  switch (true) {
    case bill < 50:
      tips.push((bill * 0.2).toFixed(2));
      break;
    case bill >= 50 && bill < 201:
      tips.push((bill * 0.15).toFixed(2));
      break;
    default:
      tips.push((bill * 0.10).toFixed(2));
  }
}
calculateTip(124);
calculateTip(48);
calculateTip(268);
console.log(tips);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a `string` representation of the `number` you call it on with the right number of decimals, but if you parse it back to `number` with `parseFloat`, those will go away, as `number` doesn't care about trailing zeros.

You can fix that by just getting rid of the `parseFloat`:

```js
const tips = [];

function calculateTip(bill) {
  if (bill < 50)
    tips.push((bill * 0.2).toFixed(2));
  else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 201)
    tips.push((bill * 0.15).toFixed(2));
  else
    tips.push((bill * 0.10).toFixed(2));
}

calculateTip(124);
calculateTip(48);
calculateTip(268);

console.log(tips);
```

Answer (score 1):

I moved the toFixed method next to your parseFloat and it returned me the result you expected:

```js
var tips = [];
var calculateTip = function(bill) {
    switch(true) {
        case bill < 50:
            tips.push(parseFloat((bill * 0.2)).toFixed(2));
            break;
        case bill >= 50 && bill < 201:
            tips.push(parseFloat((bill * 0.15)).toFixed(2));
            break;
        default:
            tips.push(parseFloat((bill * 0.10)).toFixed(2));
    }
}
calculateTip(124);
calculateTip(48);
calculateTip(217);
console.log(tips);
```